# How to estimate a delay?

Tags: control-theory, parameter-estimation, linear-control, system-identification, adaptive-control

Assume that we are using recursive least squares to estimate a transfer function

$$A(q)y(t) = B(q)u(t)$$

But the input $u(t)$ is delayed with $d$ time, eg:
$$A(q)y(t) = B(q)u(t-d)$$

How can I find the $d$ value if I have $y(t), u(t)$ saved in a list?

Comment: Do you have any assumptions on $d$, such as it is a whole number times the sample time instead of any (positive) real number?

Comment: @KwinvanderVeen Nothing. I know only $u(t), y(t)$ and I know recursive least squares from Adaptive control by Karl Johan Åström. Read that book? Well, assume that $d > 0 $